# Where to use NSString * = [DateCreated stringValue] in Obj-C?

Tags: c#, objective-c, macos, encryption

so I am coding a desktop application for Mac OS using C# and Obj-c, but am struggling to get the text from an NSTextBox as a string.

This is the returned code from ViewController.Designer.Cs (the code returned to Visual Studio from Xcode after designing the interface.

```
using Foundation;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace ByteOrbitPrivacyCannonMacBuild
{
    [Register("ViewController")]
    partial class ViewController
    {
        [Outlet]
        AppKit.NSImageView BackgroundImage { get; set; }


        [Outlet]
        AppKit.NSButton ClickButtonDecrypt { get; set; }

        public static string dtime;
        [Outlet]
        public static AppKit.NSTextField DateCreated { get; set; }

    
        [Outlet]
        AppKit.NSButton Decrypt { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        AppKit.NSButton Encrypt { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        AppKit.NSTextField Message { get; set; }

        [Action ("ClickDecrypt:")]
        partial void ClickDecrypt (Foundation.NSObject sender);

        [Action ("ClickEncrypt:")]
        partial void ClickEncrypt (Foundation.NSObject sender);

        [Action ("datecreated:")]
        partial void datecreated (Foundation.NSObject sender);

        [Action ("Okay:")]
        partial void Okay (Foundation.NSObject sender);
        
        void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
        {
            if (DateCreated != null) {
                DateCreated.Dispose ();
                DateCreated = null;
            }

            if (BackgroundImage != null) {
                BackgroundImage.Dispose ();
                BackgroundImage = null;
            }

            if (ClickButtonDecrypt != null) {
                ClickButtonDecrypt.Dispose ();
                ClickButtonDecrypt = null;
            }

            if (Decrypt != null) {
                Decrypt.Dispose ();
                Decrypt = null;
            }

            if (Encrypt != null) {
                Encrypt.Dispose ();
                Encrypt = null;
            }

            if (Message != null) {
                Message.Dispose ();
                Message = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this the ViewController code.

The

```
public static AppKit.NSTextField DateCreated { get; set; }
```

Is the returned code for the NSTextBox called DateCreated, which I am attempting to get the text string from.

Here is the ViewController:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using AppKit;
using Foundation;
using UserNotifications;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace ByteOrbitPrivacyCannonMacBuild
{
    public partial class ViewController : NSViewController
    {
        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }

        public override NSObject RepresentedObject
        {
            get
            {
                return base.RepresentedObject;
            }
            set
            {
                base.RepresentedObject = value;
                // Update the view, if already loaded.
            }
        }
        public static string ctime;
        
        partial void ClickDecrypt(Foundation.NSObject sender)
        {
            string decrypt;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"/Users/bopc/encryptedmessagehere.txt");
            string line = sr.ReadLine();

            decrypt = Encryptor1.Decrypted(Convert.ToString(line));
            Message.StringValue = line;
        
            

        }
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"encryptedmessagehere.txt");

        public static string verify;

        
        public static string verifytry;

        partial void ClickEncrypt(Foundation.NSObject sender)
        {


            verify = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
            string enctxt = Encryptor1.Encrypt(Message + " Message Created at: " + verify);
            string strPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                         System.Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"/Users/bopc/encryptedmessagehere.txt", enctxt);


        }
       
    

    }
     
}
```

I am wondering where to put the NSString * = [DateCreated stringValue] in Obj-C? Everywhere I put it returns the error "stringValue does not exist in the current context". New to MacOS development. Thank you.

Edited code:

```
[Outlet]
        public static AppKit.NSTextField DateCreated { get; set; }
        unsafe
        NSString* myStr = [DateCreated stringValue];
```

Added after advice:

```
[Outlet]
    public AppKit.NSTextField DateCreated { get; private set; }
    Console.WriteLine(DateCreated.StringValue)
```

Comment: You keep writing NSString * = [DateCreated stringValue] when it's supposed to be NSString *myStr = [DateCreated stringValue];

Comment: Thanks. And where in the compiler would I put this?  When putting what you typed it returns the error Cannot get the size of or delcare a pointer to a managed type (NSString). Thank you. See the edited code above.

Comment: [NSString C# microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsstring?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) and more specific [xamarin nsstring c# handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/ios/internals/api-design/nsstring) `Console.WriteLine(DateCreated.StringValue);`

Comment: Adding  [Outlet]
  public AppKit.NSTextField DateCreated { get; private set; }
  Console.WriteLine(DateCreated.StringValue)
(See "added after advice" above) Generates the error "Console.WriteLine does not exist in this context" and also "DateCreated.StringValue does not exist in this context". Thanks very much.

Comment: you can not mix Objective-C just so in C#, you have to use the C# language to access the API to its object classes declared from the Frameworks. look at this [xamarin question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64595015/arkit-body-tracking-using-xamarin-and-c-sharp-inaccurate) how C# looks like, there is even made use of `NSString` and its C# counterpart `string`. Take your time learning - there are even videos on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=learn+C%23). Pretty fast you will have more fun to reach your goals.

Comment: I have used C#. I am wondering though how to get the NSTextField DateCreated which was created in Xcode GUI designer as a string so I can use that string in the C# code, every tutorial I've found does not work. This is a program I already developed for Windows which I am now rebuilding for Mac OS, just having to recode the GUI for the Mac as it was originally a WinForm app. Thanks very much.

Comment: Xcode GUI designer is called Interface Builder, just in case you need to explain somewhere. NSTextField is a class that has properties and methods. one method is named `stringValue` but in C# it might be renamed to 'StringValue' because of language conventions. So your `NSTextField.StringValue` is a C# `string`. Because you don't have mono framework or xamarin or similar using i can't tell you what to code exactly. Its up to the wrapper code how the class method is accessed by property name

Comment: I am using xamarin, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Xamarin you code it like so..

```
var textfield = new NSTextField(new CGRect(0, 0, 300, 100));
textfield.StringValue = "Hello World!";
//or
NSTextField textfield = new NSTextField();
textfield.BackgroundColor = NSColor.Clear;
textfield.Bordered = false;
textfield.Selectable = false;
textfield.Editable = false;
textfield.StringValue = NSString.Create("Hello World!")
```

and the other way around

```
NSString text = new NSString();
text = textfield.StringValue;
```

```
NSString text = null;
text = "Hello World!"
NSTextField textfield = new NSTextField();
textfield.StringValue = text;
//vs.
textfield.StringValue = NSString.Create(text);
```

spot the differences when NSString is used as setter and getter. And when C# string is involved.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did work. The only issue is that the line   textfield.StringValue = NSString.Create(text);
is getting the error "NSString does not contain a definition for 'Create". Will look into why that is.

Comment: if you can tag your question with <xamarin> and vote so others find this answer easier. voting is nice those days anyway. And try `textfield.StringValue = new NSString("hello");`, apart from that have a nice read about [objc_binding with xamarin](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/main/docs/website/binding_objc_libs.md)